# Allowing my team members to sign in with Google - Flutter - Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

I added an option to sign in with Google but, to my understanding, it only works for me because my SHA-1 signature is in the Firebase settings page so it'll only work for me but not for them.

We're a team of 10 people and I don't want everyone to start adding their own signatures if possible.

Is it at all possible to make this happen in debug mode? We're not in release yet.

P.S if I'm wrong about the reason and it should work fine with only my SHA-1 fingerprint, what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's different if we deploy the app on play store, but if you've not deployed yet and just downloaded the apk from Android Studio / VS Code then anyone with a valid Gmail account can sign In.

I've also developed google sign in for my app and people are able to login.

Can you share the setup and code it can help us to narrow down the issue.